# Can't compile PIL in Virtualenv

Tags: python, xcode, macos, clang, python-imaging-library

The latest pip 1.5 and Xcode 5.1 have made it difficult to install PIL in an virtualenv.
I have googled for various solutions and it seems I had to execute these two lines:

```
export ARCHFLAGS="-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future"
pip install PIL --allow-external PIL --allow-unverified PIL
```

However I am still getting an exception and I have no idea why. My colleague on a different machine has no problem with it.

I have installed Python and latest Xcode with Commandline Tools. Maybe the latter is corrupted?

```
clang: warning: unknown argument: '-mno-fused-madd' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'

In file included from _imaging.c:75:

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/Python.h:19:

In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.1/include/limits.h:38:

/usr/include/limits.h:63:10: fatal error: 'sys/cdefs.h' file not found

#include <sys/cdefs.h>

         ^

1 error generated.

error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these to your .profile

```
export CFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
export CPPFLAGS=-Qunused-arguments
```

Comment: Can I just execute them in the terminal or does it really have to be in the .profile? If the latter is true, where do I find the .profile please? thanks

Comment: You can just execute them before you run your pip install <stuff>. But if you want to add them to your .profile, simply cd ~ then vim .profile to add

Comment: excellent. I just tried it, however the error is still there. :( What am I missing?

Comment: I had the same issue last month, and it was torturing. I had to format my Mac. But you shouldn't, I would suggest to uninstall Commandline Tools, then install again to try fresh.

Also Quit your terminal, and open it before you try to pip install PIL. Make sure you run the two export commands.

Comment: Thank you so much, uninstalling and reinstalling the command-line tools solved the problem.